# How to remove this ceiling lamp cover held together with three metal latches

Tags: lamp

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to remove this ceiling lamp cover.

I need to change the light bulb inside.

[image]

The three metal hooks there are held to the base of the lamp with these:

[image]

The metal hooks are very rigid. I don't think I can force them open enough to squeeze the glass lamp cover through them.

Here are two more picture of the rivets and latches holding this god forsaken lamp cover:

[image]

I'm stuck :(

Comment: The metal hooks may be a bracket that is latched to the frame or box. See if you can firmly grab the metal hooks and gently twist the fixture and more gently pull down. Probably counter clockwise.

Comment: Can you take pictures of the other two clamps as well (with a slight side view)? I'd like to see if they are all flat headless screws, and for the one pictured, is there ridges on the side that a hand or pliers can grab to unscrew (counter clockwise)..... otherwise I'd haveto concur with @RetiredMasterElectrician

Comment: The picture is far to dark to make anything notable out, but I still want to ensure they aren't thumb screws. Your newest picture looks less like what @RetiredMasterElectrician suggested as possible because there doesn't appear to be a denotation oe separate of the white clamp holder frame from the base of the bulb (but it is still possible).

Comment: Typically these kinds of fixtures have one clip that you pull straight out away from the fixture that allows the glass to slide out of the other two

Comment: I've cropped the pics to relevant areas & punched up the detail in Photoshop as much as possible [needs approval as I'm low-rep here]. They look like rivets not screws of any sort to me. I'd be tempted to pull each outward, see if one is sprung.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to post after wondering this myself and figuring it out via a youtube video I came across. There's three clips but one kind of has a spring mechanism that you can pull out until it clears the glass or plastic fixture, after that you tilt down the glass slightly from the other clips until it just slides out. I know this is an old post but just wanted to add this so you don't need to do extra research like I had to.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it's easy when you know how.

The bolts attached to the metal rim of the light fixture (the part that's tight to the ceiling) are not the adjustable part.

Instead, the other part of them, the decorative metal clips that the glass bowl sits in are fairly flexible.

Here's how you remove the glass shade:

Cupping the glass shade in one hand, gently pry (with your finger) ONE of the decorative clips it sits in up toward the ceiling away from the glass bowl.

From here, you should be able to angle the glass bowl downward and out.

To put the glass bowl back in place once you've changed the bulb, pull back one of the decorative metal clips toward the ceiling and angle the shade back in,
letting the decorative clip gently flip back to hold the glass in place.

Good luck and be careful with electricity!
Always turn off the power.

Comment: OP indicated that the metal clips are NOT springy and cannot be bent out to remove the glass.

Comment: OPs aren't always right. This answer seems correct to me.

Comment: This answer is wrong,  and the one from Chris is correct. I have several of this model at home.

Answer (score -1):

Loosen the bolt one by one but not remove it. You can unscrew the first one more liberally than the other two. Usually, the cover will come loose after loosen two of the bolts, or with the third one just loosen slightly to release the tight grab.

Comment: All indications were that those are NOT screws.

Comment: @FreeMan If nothing to loosen/release, how to replace the light bulb, or remove the lighting fixture if necessary (it couldn't be installed in the first place).

Comment: It's a 2 year old question, so it's probably moot, but, it could be a push fit or the white ring could screw in/out. OP never came back, so who knows.

Comment: Some lighting frame has L-shaped slot for the removal of cover through rotation, but there is no such slot in this photo.

Comment: Two of the clips are fixed, but the third has a spring mechanism: it can be pulled horizontally outwards (away from the center of the circular fixture) enough that the glass can be removed.